# building binutils before gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, binutils

I am trying to build a gcc cross compiler. I understand that before compiling the cross compiler I need to have the target binutils built already. why the building of the compiler need the target binutils ? the compiler alone only takes high level code and turn it to the assembly that I defined it in the compiler sources. so why do I need the target bintools for compiling the cross compiler ? It is written in all of the cross compiler documentation that I need them to be build before compiling the cross compiler. (e.g. http://wiki.osdev.org/Building_GCC and  http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~nakazato/tips/xgcc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key question seems to be:

> why the building of the compiler need the target binutils ?

As described in [Building a cross compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html#TOC1), part of the build process for a GNU cross-compiler is to build runtime libraries for the target using the newly-compiled cross-compiler. So the `binutils` for the target need to be present for that step to succeed.

It *may* be possible to build the cross-compiler first, using empty files for the subset of `binutils` components that `gcc` needs - such as `as` and `ld` and `ar` and `ranlib` - *then* build and install the target `binutils` components into the proper locations, *then* build the target runtime libraries.

But it would be less error-prone to do things the following way (and the documentation recommends this): build `binutils` for the target first, place the specified executables in `gcc`'s source tree, then build the cross-compiler.

Answer (score 2):

GCC needs an assembler to transform the assembly it generates into object files (machine code), and a linker to link object files together to produce executables and shared libraries. It also needs an archiver to produce static libraries/archives.

Those three are usually provided by the [binutils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils) package (among other useful tools): the GNU assembler `as`, linker `ld` and the `ar` archiver.

Comment: I am compiling the cross compiler on linux and it will run on linux but will produce exe file for other machine (host != linux). So when I compile the cross compiler I need to use the as and ld of the current OS that I am in. So in my understanding ,in order to compile the cross compiler I do not need the host binutils. I only need the host bintools whenever I want to compile sources for the host, and than the output from the cross compiler while have to use as and ld for the host. So my qeustion is, why do I need them before compiling the cross compiler ?

Comment: You need at least the assembler to build things like `crt*.o` for the target, and probably linker too (esp. if you're going to build the C++ standard library).

Comment: Ok , I understand that when compiling sources for the target I need the target bintools but it doesn't answer the question why do I need them to build the cross compiler. I am not going to run the cross compiler on the target... I run it on the host but take the exe file it generate and run them on the target.... BTW in the above comment when I wrote host I meant target.

Comment: The C runtime "startup"/teardown files `crt*.o` are in target machine code. They don't run on the host, they're linked into target binaries. And they're not built each time you compile some code, they're built as part of the (cross-)compiler.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need the target bintools in order to link the crt.o files. And that is done when building the cross compiler ?! BTW it can't be object file because it means that crt file already compiled, but how they compiled without the cross compiler to specify the available instructions ?

Comment: You're building the cross-compiler. Towards the end of the build, the cross-compiler is ready to run. It can compile code for the target.

Answer (score 0):

The binutils (binary utilities) provide `low-level handling of
binary files`, such as `linking`, `assembling`, and `parsing ELF files`. The GCC
compiler depends on these tools to create an `executable`, because it generates
object files that binutils assemble into an executable image.

ELF is the format that Linux uses for binary executable
files. The `GCC` compiler relies on `binutils` to provide much of the `platform-specific functionality`.

Here your are cross-compiling for some other architecture not for x86. So resulting binutils are `platform-specific`

while configuring has to give --host!=target. i.e --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu
where --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi.
So resulting executable are not same which host already having binutils.

**addition**
the basic things needs to be known.

The `build machine`, where the toolchain is built.

The `host machine`, where the toolchain will be executed.

The `target machine`, where the binaries created by the
toolchain are executed.

So binutils will be having  tools to generate and manipulate binaries
for a given CPU architecture. Not for the one host is using

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - why do I need the target bintools before I can compile the cross compiler ?